# Is there a phrase in Japanese that means "anything under the sun"?

Tags: idioms

The English idiom "anything under the sun" means, anything at all. For example:

> We sat and talked about anything under the sun.

Is there a Japanese phrase with the same nuance as that? The sentence:

> 私たちは座って色々な事について話しました。

doesn't seem to "catch" the nuance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my E-J dictionaries...

> under the sun ｟略式｠(1) この世で[の]、天が下に[の]. **(2) [everything under the sun] ありとあらゆること.** (3) [nothing under the sun] 全く何も…ない. [4]｟まれ｠[通例 What...? 構文で] いったいぜんたい.
> (Taishukan's Genius English-Japanese Dictionary)

> under the sun ① この世の[で] There is nothing new under the sun. 日の下に新しきものなし[←Bible *Eccl* 1:9] **② すべての、いろいろな I tried everything under the sun. ありとあらゆることをすべて試した**
> (Obunsha's Lexis English-Japanese Dictionary)

"Anything under the sun" in your sentence is used in the sense of #2 in both dictionaries, so I think it can be translated as:

> 私たちは座って、ありとあらゆることについて話しました。
> 私たちは座って、ありとあらゆるすべてのことについて話しました。

Answer (score 3):

**森羅｛しんら｝万象｛ばんしょう｝**

森羅｛しんら｝万象｛ばんしょう｝ means *all things in nature*.

> 森羅万象とは天地間に存在するありとあらゆる事象のこと。
> Translation: 森羅万象 literally means *every phenomenon or thing existing between the sky (/the heavens) and the ground (/the earth)*.

I'm sorry to say that 森羅万象 is solemn, but is not so friendly.

Similar to 森羅万象, there is another expression **天地｛てんち｝万物｛ばんぶつ｝** that means *the whole creation* or *everything in heaven and earth*.

**天地万物** consists of **天** *heaven*, **地** *earth* and **万物** *everything* (**万** *ten thousands* / *a lot of* and **物** *thing*).

天地万物 is not so solemn as 森羅万象, but is also not so friendly.

There are some adverbs similar to the expression anything "*under the sun*":

- 満｛まん｝天下｛てんか｝に： *under the sky*
- お天道｛てんとう｝様｛さま｝の下｛もと／した｝で： *with the sun / under the sun*